# How to send multiple dicts to pytest fixture as a parameter

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to write a test to pass valid and invalid proxy details. I have written a Pytest fixture which will do request and return the response. But my problem is that I would like to send invalid and valid proxy details during fixture. Can someone correct me whether this approach is correct or suggest me with the valid approach, I am new to Pytests. I have tried the following way.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
@pytest.mark.parametrize("proxyDict",[
    ({
        "http": "web-proxy.testsite:8080",
        "https": "web-proxy.testsite:8080"
        }),
({
        "http": "web-wrong:8080",
        "https": "web-.wrong:8080"
        })
])
def cve_response(proxy_dict):
    year="2018"
    base_url = 'https://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-' + str(year) + '.json.zip'
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }
    response_data = requests.request("GET", base_url, headers=headers, verify=False, stream=True,
                                         proxies=proxy_dict)
    yield response_data

@pytest.mark.proxy
def test_valid_proxy(cve_response):
    assert 200 == cve_response.status_code

@pytest.mark.invalidproxy
def test_invalid_proxy(cve_response):
    assert not 200 == cve_response.status_code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parameterize your test cases and not your fixture. Also, this is not a use case for using fixtures. So, instead here's how you should handle it:

```
data = [{
            "http": "web-proxy.testsite:8080",
            "https": "web-proxy.testsite:8080"
        },
        {
            "http": "web-wrong:8080",
            "https": "web-.wrong:8080"
        }]

def cve_response(proxy_dict):
    year="2018"
    base_url = 'https://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-' + str(year) + '.json.zip'
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }
    response_data = requests.request("GET", base_url, headers=headers, verify=False, stream=True,
                                         proxies=proxy_dict)
    return response_data

@pytest.mark.proxy
@pytest.mark.parameterize("proxy", data)
def test_valid_proxy(proxy):
    assert 200 == cve_response(proxy).status_code

@pytest.mark.invalidproxy
@pytest.mark.parameterize("proxy", data)
def test_invalid_proxy(proxy):
    assert not 200 == cve_response(proxy).status_code
```

> You can choose to have different data for the positive and negative scenarios depending on the requirement.